# How to overload tab key besides transferring focus

Tags: java, swing

So i try to design a component (only have access to this component), and when the user hit tab key depends on the value of a variable x, the component should behave differently.

Let's say if x is 1, transfer the focus to next component (what tab normally does).
If x is 2, do something else (this component consists of 3 smaller component, the "something else" here refers to transfer focus between those 3 smaller component).

Currently I accomplished then case for x = 2 i used a key listener to do this, but now if x = 1 and I hit tab key, the focus won't transfer to the next component.

So how can I add some new functionality to tab key while still keep its old functionality?

Comment: Are you trying to validate user input perhaps?

Comment: actually not, so the component i am designing has 3 smaller components, so the tab key will be either used to transfer focus between the smaller component or transfer focus to the next component

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear which part you're having a problem with: detecting when the user hits the tab key, or the transferring focus, or the `if (x==1)` part.

Have you looked at this? 
docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html

You can add a keyboard listener that calls the appropriate component's `requestFocusInWindow();` method to transfer focus.

Make sure to set each component to be focusable with `setFocusable(true);`

Comment: sorry being unclear, I updated my question. My bug is the transferring focus part (stated in the question). Also, I only have access to the component I am designing

Comment: Ah. What about if you call `super.actionPerformed (e);` in your key listener when `x==1`? That should call tab's default behavior.